# Using nth-last-child() to hide last pages of will-paginate not working

Tags: html, css, pagination, will-paginate

I wanted to hide the last pages of will paginate so instead of this:

prev | 1 2 .. 5 **6** 7 .. 30 31 | next

it would look like this:

prev | 1 2 .. 5 **6** 7 .. | next

The html code generated by will-paginate is as follows

```html
<ul class="pagination pagination">
  <li class="prev">
    <a rel="prev" href="/videos?page=5">← Previous</a>
  </li> 
  <li>
    <a rel="start" href="/videos?page=1">1</a>
  </li> 
  <li>
    <a href="/videos?page=2">2</a>
  </li> 
  <li class="disabled">
    <span>…</span>
  </li> 
  <li>
    <a rel="prev" href="/videos?page=5">5</a>
  </li> 
  <li class="active">
    <span>6</span>
  </li> 
  <li>
    <a rel="next" href="/videos?page=7">7</a>
  </li> <li class="disabled">
  <span>…</span>
  </li> 
  <li>
    <a href="/videos?page=30">30</a>
  </li> 
  <li>
    <a href="/videos?page=31">31</a>
  </li> 
  <li class="next">
    <a rel="next" href="/videos?page=7">Next →</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to hide the last pages through the following css:

```css
.pagination_links li:nth-last-child(1) {
 display : none !important;
 text-decoration: none !important;
}

.pagination_links li:nth-last-child(2) {
 display : none !important;
 text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

I also thought maybe I had to hide the actual href div and not the li so I tried this too:

```css
.pagination_links li:nth-last-child(1) a {
 display : none !important;
 text-decoration: none !important;
}

.pagination_links li:nth-last-child(2) a {
 display : none !important;
 text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

Still nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: Voting to close as a "typo" question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo, change `<ul class="pagination pagination">` to `<ul class="pagination pagination_links">`

Also if you want something like
`<-pre 1 2 ...6 7 ...->next`, you need to change your css to

```
.pagination_links li:nth-last-child(2) a {  
    display : none !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}

.pagination_links li:nth-last-child(3) a {
    display : none !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

Because `.pagination_links li:nth-last-child(1)` is `next->`

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add this class `pagination_links` to the `ul`.

```css
.pagination_links li:nth-last-child(1) {
 display : none !important;
 text-decoration: none !important;
}

.pagination_links li:nth-last-child(2) {
 display : none !important;
 text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

```html
<ul class="pagination pagination_links">
  <li class="prev">
    <a rel="prev" href="/videos?page=5">← Previous</a>
  </li> 
  <li>
    <a rel="start" href="/videos?page=1">1</a>
  </li> 
  <li>
    <a href="/videos?page=2">2</a>
  </li> 
  <li class="disabled">
    <span>…</span>
  </li> 
  <li>
    <a rel="prev" href="/videos?page=5">5</a>
  </li> 
  <li class="active">
    <span>6</span>
  </li> 
  <li>
    <a rel="next" href="/videos?page=7">7</a>
  </li> <li class="disabled">
  <span>…</span>
  </li> 
  <li>
    <a href="/videos?page=30">30</a>
  </li> 
  <li>
    <a href="/videos?page=31">31</a>
  </li> 
  <li class="next">
    <a rel="next" href="/videos?page=7">Next →</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```